# Logistic Regression in R with different results when I want interaction effect

Tags: logistic

My dependent variable is Accuracy (that takes 1 or 0 for right and wrong). My IVs are Emotion (Sad, Happy; coded as 1,2 respectively), Load (high or low coded as 1,2 respectively) and Group (Group A and Group B; coded as 1,2 respectively).

I'm running a logistic regression in R using the following formula:

```
model1 <- glm(Accuracy ~ Emotion + Group + Load, data = file_name, family = Binomial(link = "logit")
```

`summary(model1)` gives me a result that I can interpret. However, I notice that the Emotion and Group variables are followed by a number:

[image: Main Effect]

I'm new to logistic regression, but I'm not sure why its giving a specific result for an emotion. Why does it say `emotion2` instead of `emotion`? Usually, in ANOVA, I get a simple effect of IVs and then I look inside to know the sub-factors affecting the DV. Why is this different?

Moreover, I'm interested in knowing the interaction effect. So, I executed another command:

```
model11 <- glm(Accuracy ~ Emotion * Task * Group, data = file_name,
      family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

`summary(model11)` gives me something completely different. I had expected that the main effect will be the same for the two models (`model1` and `model11`), but this is not the case.

[image: Regression with Interaction Effects]

Can anyone explain why this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

> why does it say emotion2 instead of emotion

Emotion is likely coded as a factor.  The model assumes that emotion=1 is the comparison group.  The coefficient for emotion 2 is the log odds ratio of emotion=2 as compared to emotion =1.

> summary(model11) gives me something completely different

Those are huge odds ratios.  I suspect there is some strong correlation between covariates causing these enormous odds ratios.

Comment: The covariates aren't necessarily correlated--this looks like an experiment, they're probably orthogonal. Rather, there is complete separation here.